# How to do filter in angular material data table for specific column

Tags: angular6, angular-material-6

i am trying angular material data table.

As we know filtering happened for each row by default.

If i want to filter column specific, then what should i do?

Should i have to write method for getting all records, then iterate over it and compare specific column?

component.ts

---

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getUser().subscribe( results => {
        if(!results){

          return;
        }
        console.log(results);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    })


onSearchClear(){
    this.searchKey="";
    this.applyFilter();
  }

  applyFilter(){
    this.dataSource.filter = this.searchKey.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

component.html

---

```
<mat-form-field class="search-form-field">
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchKey" placeholder="search by userName" (keyup)="applyFilter()">
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should use filterPredicate property of [MatTableDataSource](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource)

after you initialize this.dataSource, define a custom filterPredicate function as follows;

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results);
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data: any, filterValue: string) {
  return data.specificColumn /** replace this with the column name you want to filter */
    .trim()
    .toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue.trim().toLocaleLowerCase()) >= 0;
};
```

Comment: this will do exact match....if i want to match a part of any username...

suppose mohan is the userName, and if i enter moh....it is not showing that

Comment: i have updated my answer to include partial match. please take a look.

Comment: where is this.sort coming from?

Comment: `this.sort` it is an instance of [MatSort](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource) defined within the component class but not shared in the question. My answer just refers to the code provided in the question.

Comment: also please see the following https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview

Answer (score 8):

Check [this](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-material-table-custom-filter-using-select-box/) tutorial and working [demo](https://freakyjolly.com/demo/Angular/angular-material-table-custom-filters-for-multiple-specific-column/)

[image]