# Filter data in Angular when click button

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm Working with Angular 10 and Angular Material. I have a mat-table where I display some data, my array where I took that data is:

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {invoice: 1, category: 'Hydrogen', description: 'Hello World!.', startDate: 'H', status: '1', see: '', department: 'Bugambilias', floor: 1, unit: 603, classification: 'Mantenimiento', subcategory: 'Seguridad', type: '1'},
  {invoice: 2, category: 'Helium', description: 'Hello World!.', startDate: 'He', status: '1', see: '', department: 'Bugambilias', floor: 2, unit: 603, classification: 'Mantenimiento', subcategory: 'Seguridad', type: '2'},
  {invoice: 3, category: 'Lithium', description: 'Hello World!.', startDate: 'Li', status: '1', see: '', department: 'Bugambilias', floor: 3, unit: 603, classification: 'Mantenimiento', subcategory: 'Seguridad', type: '1'},
  {invoice: 4, category: 'Beryllium', description: 'Hello World!.', startDate: 'Be', status: '1', see: '', department: 'Bugambilias', floor: 4, unit: 603, classification: 'Mantenimiento', subcategory: 'Seguridad', type: '1'},
  {invoice: 5, category: 'Boron', description: 'Hello World!.', startDate: 'B', status: '1', see: '', department: 'Bugambilias', floor: 5, unit: 603, classification: 'Mantenimiento', subcategory: 'Seguridad', type: '1'},
  {invoice: 6, category: 'Carbon', description: 'Hello World!.', startDate: 'C', status: '1', see: '', department: 'Bugambilias', floor: 6, unit: 603, classification: 'Mantenimiento', subcategory: 'Seguridad', type: '2'},
  {invoice: 7, category: 'Nitrogen', description: 'Hello World!.', startDate: 'N', status: '1', see: '', department: 'Bugambilias', floor: 7, unit: 603, classification: 'Mantenimiento', subcategory: 'Seguridad', type: '2'},
  {invoice: 8, category: 'Oxygen', description: 'Hello World!.', startDate: 'O', status: '1', see: '', department: 'Bugambilias', floor: 8, unit: 603, classification: 'Mantenimiento', subcategory: 'Seguridad', type: '2'},
  {invoice: 9, category: 'Fluorine', description: 'Hello World!.', startDate: 'F', status: '1', see: '', department: 'Bugambilias', floor: 9, unit: 603, classification: 'Mantenimiento', subcategory: 'Seguridad', type: '2'},
  {invoice: 10, category: 'Neon', description: 'Hello World!.', startDate: 'Ne', status: '1', see: '', department: 'Bugambilias', floor: 10, unit: 603, classification: 'Mantenimiento', subcategory: 'Seguridad', type: '1'},
];
```

[image]

On the top, I have some buttons to filter the data, I know how to filter it with the 'type' value (the last one) but I have some troubles to show the filtered data when I click the buttons.

[image]

Those are my buttons that filter the rows that contains the specific data.

Does anyone know how to do this filter?

PS. If you need more information please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: can you try to host this on code sandbox so we can re create your problem ?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late. Here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/live/y0vl61g

Answer (score 2):

it's already answered [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56620674/how-to-do-filter-in-angular-material-data-table-for-specific-column)

code :

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data: any, filterValue: string) {
  return data.specificColumn /** replace this with the column name you want to filter */
    .trim()
    .toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue.trim().toLocaleLowerCase()) >= 0;
};
```